# $\nabla_\mu X^{\nu} = \delta^{\nu}_{\mu}$ ? Covariant derivative of coordinate

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Let the coordinate on a $d$-dimensional manifold be given by $X^{\mu}$. I wish to know what is $\nabla_{\nu}X^{\mu} = ?$ i.e. the covariant derivative of a coordinate ? I understand that this maybe an ill-defined object, so please just humor me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A coordinate is a scalar function of the point, so it makes sense to take its derivative, a gradient in this case. If you move along the corresponding coordinate line, the rate of increase is clearly $1$. If you move along any other coordinate line, it does not change and the derivative is zero. That is why the result is $\delta_\mu^\nu$.

Comment: So you mean to say $\nabla_{\mu}X^{\nu} = \partial_{\mu}X^{\nu}$ ?

Comment: Yes. For scalar functions covariant derivatives are just partial derivatives.